# Fonts Not showing Up - Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, locale

I installed Debian 8 and chrome

When i visit google.co.in the various languages are showing as boxes.

[image: The Languages selection are showing as boxes]

Tried `dkpg-locale reconfigure` nothing works.

Comment: You need to have installed the appropriate font packages.

Comment: FWIW these are some likely candidates: `fonts-dejavu-extra` `fonts-freefont-ttf` `fonts-liberation` `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` `ttf-unifont`

Comment: Do i need to install all the languages separately ,for hindi, tamil ?

Comment: I believe those packages should give you fonts that work, the indian google page displays correctly here in all languages and I never made an effort to support those (I can't read those anyway...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display non-ASCII characters you need to have the appropriate font packages installed; glyphs that can't be displayed will be shown as a box outline.

I generally have the following font packages installed in Debian and see most languages in their own font:

- fonts-dejavu-extra
- fonts-freefont-ttf
- fonts-liberation
- ttf-mscorefonts-installer
- ttf-unifont

Perhaps you only need one or two, but these give a reasonably complete coverage in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of meta-packages which provide the necessary support:

- `fonts-deva` for Devanagari;
- `fonts-beng` for Bengali;
- `fonts-telu` for Telugu;
- `fonts-taml` for Tamil;
- `fonts-gujr` for Gujarati;
- `fonts-knda` for Kannada.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using google.co.in , you may need to install fonts for Indian languages.

`fonts-indic` is a meta-package which installs all the Indian language free fonts available in debian. Simply install it by

```
#apt-get install fonts-indic
```